# How to filter leads by field_data or id?

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get leads and filter them by lead ID or `field_data`. I'm using the Facebook NodeJS SDK but neither got it working in the GraphQL Explorer.

What's the issue?
I want to filter leads by id or field_data but I'm getting An unknown error has occurred.

GraphQL query:
807167831236778 is the leadgen form
ID is the Facebook lead ID

`807167831236778/leads?fields=id&filtering=[{"field":"id","operator":"EQUAL","value":"346632491054423"}]`

NodeJS SDK

```js
const params = {
  // trying to filter a specific lead id
  'filtering' : [{'field':'id','operator':'EQUAL','value':'123456'}],
};
const leadgenFormLeads = await (new LeadgenForm(form.id)).getLeads([
                Lead.Fields.campaign_name,
                Lead.Fields.created_time,
                Lead.Fields.field_data,
                Lead.Fields.form_id
            ], params).then((result) => result.map((lead) => lead._data))
```